# using a linksys wireless-g router with verizon dsl modem

Tags: router, dsl

I am currently using:

1. Westell 6100 verizon dsl modem
2. Linksys wireless-g router

I can't get the router to connect to the internet with wired or wireless connection when linked to the modem; but the modem can access the internet when the computer is connected directly to it.

Any help in getting the router to work would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I had almost the exact same question today (but with a Linksys E1500)! Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the modem bridged and connected to the WAN port of the router and is the router configured to supply IP to your LAN (DHCP)?

Anyways I think you can get some ideas here: [westell 6100 and routers](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/13600)

Comment: Thank you very much... the linked article solved everything for me... both wifi and wired connection off of the router works perfectly... the only step i was missing was the last part to clone the mac address of the modem... thx again

Comment: happy to help you solve the problem! I linked the article because the 6100 is a modem and a router so its configuration is not as easy as a simple modem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the IP addresses of the modem and router are conflicting.  You'll need to access the control panel for either the router or the modem and change the IP address of one of them.  To change the IP address of your router go to `http://192.168.1.1` and the username and password will either be "admin" and the password field will be left blank, or "admin" for both the username and password (assuming you haven't changed them).  Then you will need to change the IP address for the router (I suggest `192.168.1.10`).  After you have changed the IP address everything should work.

Comment: already tried that... just changing the IP addresses of the modem and the router doesn't do anything... thx anyway